# Как вывести данные из массива?

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
<?php
$wall = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=vcru&offset=1&count=1&filter=all'), true);
print_r ($wall);
?>
```

Результат работы **$wall**

```
   Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20209
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 362198
                    [from_id] => -33393308
                    [to_id] => -33393308
                    [date] => 1460625484
                    [post_type] => post
                    [text] => «В день эфира мы получили 70% дополнительных установок за один час эфира. Цена за одну установку составила $0,4. Вечернее шоу с гостями дало нам показательный прирост установок, а 10-секундные упоминания практически не давали дополнительные инсталляции». <br><br>В рубрике #growthhacks — кейс с бесплатным продвижением мобильного приложения на радио «Спорт ФМ».<br><br>https://vc.ru/p/365scores-radio
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => link
                            [link] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => https://vc.ru/p/365scores-radio
                                    [title] => Кейс из России: Бесплатное продвижение мобильного приложения на радио «Спорт ФМ»
                                    [description] => PR-менеджер LETA Capital Светлана Молчанова поделилась с редакторами рубрики Growth Hacks опытом продвижения мобильного приложения 365Scores с помощью бартерного проекта с радиостанцией «Спорт ФМ».
                                    [image_src] => http://cs636430.vk.me/v636430513/1f5f/WxU36fFLrP0.jpg
                                    [image_big] => http://cs636430.vk.me/v636430513/1f61/k4vOdsDHHY0.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [attachments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => link
                                    [link] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://vc.ru/p/365scores-radio
                                            [title] => Кейс из России: Бесплатное продвижение мобильного приложения на радио «Спорт ФМ»
                                            [description] => PR-менеджер LETA Capital Светлана Молчанова поделилась с редакторами рубрики Growth Hacks опытом продвижения мобильного приложения 365Scores с помощью бартерного проекта с радиостанцией «Спорт ФМ».
                                            [image_src] => http://cs636430.vk.me/v636430513/1f5f/WxU36fFLrP0.jpg
                                            [image_big] => http://cs636430.vk.me/v636430513/1f61/k4vOdsDHHY0.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                    [likes] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 25
                        )

                    [reposts] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Как эхом(echo) вывести только **image_big** ?

Comment: или в свежих версиях php array_column

Comment: @splash58 как тут `array_column` поможет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не помогает, обновил код для большей ясности вопроса

Comment: @splash58 не помогает

Comment: Если вы укажете где в получаемом ответе поле `src_big`, то вам дадут нобеля

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извиняюсь это старый массив, просто данные с вк подтягиваю.
Обновил все.Надо вывести image_big

Comment: `echo $arr['response'][cellNumber]['attachment']['link']['image_big']` / echo `$arr['response'][cellNumber]['attachments'][cellNumberForAttachments]['link']['‌​image_big']`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский отлично спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение №1. По заданию через `echo`

```
$wall = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=vcru&offset=1&count=1&filter=all'), true);
array_walk_recursive($wall, function($value, $key) {
  if ($key === 'image_big')
    echo $value.'<br>';
});
```

Решение №2. Через замыкание формируем массив. (php >= 5.3.0)

```
$wall = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=vcru&offset=1&count=1&filter=all'), true);
$images = array();
array_walk_recursive($wall, function($value, $key) use (&$images) {
  if ($key === 'image_big')
    $images[] = $value;
});
print_r($images);
```